# Skrollr transform functioncauses text shivering

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, skrollr

using skrollr.js i am gonna doing some transition effect on an inner div which is ivside another div. The inner div is relative positioned .

### My codes are

### HTML Structure

```
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner-div" style="transition:transform .3s ease;" data-top="transform:translateY(0px)" data--80p-top="transform:translateY(300px)">
     <h1>some thing</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

the problem is when scrolling it( `h1` ) creates a great shivering vertically
What can be the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Just a small pointer, I made a similar mistake using scrollr.js, initially:

```
  <div class="inner-div" style="transition:transform .3s ease;" data-top="transform:translateY(0px)" data--80p-top="transform:translateY(300px)">
```

scrollr.js allows negative index, but why do you need that? Try the below code:

```
 <div class="inner-div" style="transition:transform .3s ease;" data-0="transform:translateY(0px)" data-80p-top="transform:translateY(300px)">
```

The effect you're after is pretty straightforward and if you have the time, go though [the examples of Scrollr.js](https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr/tree/master/examples), it's a well-documented plugin.

Comment: positive index on that causes the text transfrom from lower to upper when scrolling down

Comment: @muhaimin but does it have the same bug as with negative index ?